# WPF listbox with image, how to dynamycally change image on condition

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

I'm new in WPF and i'm exploring listbox control.
I created a listbox, items represent image plus text.

Xaml code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LstB_Checklist" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="139" Margin="48,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Checked}" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/listbox;component/Pictures/BulletOff.png"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Checked}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/listbox;component/Pictures/BulletOn.png"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

the binding allows to properly set items and image at startup.

Code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<LstB_Item> items = new List<LstB_Item>();
        items.Add(new LstB_Item() { Title = "Item1", Checked = "false" });
        items.Add(new LstB_Item() { Title = "Item2", Checked = "false" });            
        LstB_Checklist.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    public class LstB_Item
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Checked { get; set; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //
    }
```

I would like to know how to change the image according to some conditions, when i clik on a button (e.g selected item image turn to "bulletOn" instead of "bulltOff" according to external condition, not based on "onselect" trigger)

Many thanks

Comment: Making the LstB_Item class implement INotifPropertyChanged (and firing the PropertyChanged event when the Checked property changes) should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain how to implement property change event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Clemens suggests the class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise change notifications whenever the Checked property is set to a new value:

```
public class LstB_Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        private string _checked;
        public string Checked
        {
            get { return _checked; }
            set { _checked = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

You should then be able to simply change the value of the Checked property for the item that you want to change the image for:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<LstB_Item> items = LstB_Checklist.ItemsSource as List<LstB_Item>;
    items[0].Checked = "true";
}
```

Please refer to MSDN for more information about the INotifyPropertyChanged interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

You should also consider changing the type of your Checked property from string to bool:

```
        private bool _checked;
        public bool Checked
        {
            get { return _checked; }
            set { _checked = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

Comment: Many thanks both of you. It works and totaly answer my question